# Which wallets are spending P2TR with SIGHASH_ALL?

Tags: wallet, taproot, schnorr-signatures, p2tr, sighash-flags

I noticed there are quite a lot of transactions spending taproot key path inputs that use `SIGHASH_ALL` instead of `SIGHASH_DEFAULT` in signatures (around 20% in the last two weeks). Recall that `SIGHASH_DEFAULT` is a sighash flag introduced in [BIP341](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0341.mediawiki) that is equivalent to `SIGHASH_ALL` but saves 1 witness byte.

Example transactions: (all from block 799301)

[14a5060a907fa55b19fb75173236acee077792816b6cd8d97e3ae226b4acab6a](https://mempool.space/tx/14a5060a907fa55b19fb75173236acee077792816b6cd8d97e3ae226b4acab6a)
[8c4dcdb47b2e806f1dd2c306e5021bc1b3eb763bf98d3a9b26081e273da55bfe](https://mempool.space/tx/8c4dcdb47b2e806f1dd2c306e5021bc1b3eb763bf98d3a9b26081e273da55bfe)
[552b20e3d4b4d97bd03cd8f58fe6979fae74d04cead37f080692a1f6d30356bc](https://mempool.space/tx/552b20e3d4b4d97bd03cd8f58fe6979fae74d04cead37f080692a1f6d30356bc)
[a81d9024708a255b5563dca9c4baf5b0056424fb329840ac97428e814054994e](https://mempool.space/tx/a81d9024708a255b5563dca9c4baf5b0056424fb329840ac97428e814054994e)

Which wallets are creating these signatures, and why?